# Knockout.JS: get data

Tags: knockout.js

I know this may seem too easy, but I'm trying to understand how Knockout works. What am I doing wrong ? I need to get, for each student, data about "Note", but the method I've tried doesnt seem to work... I'd appreciate any kind of help or advices.

```
 <table data-bind="foreach: students">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nume</th>
            <th>Prenume</th>
            <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" size="1" data-bind="value: StudId" disabled="disabled"></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="60" data-bind="value: Nume" disabled="disabled"></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="60" data-bind="value: Prenume" disabled="disabled"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="15" data-bind="value: Data" disabled="disabled">
                <input data-bind="click: $parent.deleteStudent.bind($parent, $data.StudId)" type="button" value="Sterge" class="button button1" id="sterge" />
                <input data-bind="click: function() { $parent.loadNote.bind($parent, $data.StudId); alert(NotaId); }" type="button" class="button button2" value="Note" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And Knockout one:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var uri = 'api/student';

        var StudentsViewModel = function () {
            this.students = ko.observableArray();
            this.note = ko.observableArray();

            this.loadNote();
            this.loadStudents();
        };

        StudentsViewModel.prototype.loadStudents = function () {
            var self = this;
            $.getJSON(uri, function (data) {
                self.students(data);
            });
        };

        StudentsViewModel.prototype.loadNote = function (id) {
            var self = this;
            $.getJSON(uri + '/' + id, function (data) {
                self.note(data);
            });
        };
// Apply bindings
        ko.applyBindings(new StudentsViewModel());
```

Why doesn't it show "Note" when I press the button for each student?

Comment: Since you get HTTP error 400 (Bad Request) you have to check the server side script that generates this error. Also you can inspect all network requests and responses in browser's devtools (F12 key by default).

Answer (score 1):

When you call `bind` on a function, the function is not *called*. Instead, `bind` returns a *new* function with a bound `this` context and optional bound parameters.

This means that this function:

```
function() { 
  $parent.loadNote.bind($parent, $data.StudId); 
  alert(NotaId); 
}
```

Won't call `loadNote`. You'd need another set of parentheses to call the newly created function:

```
$parent.loadNote.bind($parent, $data.StudId)();
```

It's best to not create new functions in your data-binds, especially if you're not really familiar with knockout. It can get a bit messy with the `click` parameters and `bindingContext`.

I'd suggest adding an `onLoadNoteClick` method to your viewmodel, changing your binding to `click: onLoadNoteClick`, and creating a breakpoint in this method. Then, you can check `arguments` to see what's passed, and `this` to see the method's context.

Comment: I am getting "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)"

Answer (score 0):

In your function `loadNote`, you set `var self=this;`

As the error says, there is no `note` function in the current closure.
Try setting `self` in the constructor but don't limit it to the constructor scope so you can call it later.

```
var uri = 'api/student';
var self;
var StudentsViewModel = function () {
    self=this;
    this.students = ko.observableArray();
    this.note = ko.observableArray();
    this.loadNote();
    this.loadStudents();
    };
```

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: How can I fix it ?

Comment: as mentioned by @f_martinez in his comment, the best you can do for the moment is check the call to the server you are making using the browser tool (F12). It is quite possible that your knockout/javascript is working just fine but your server call is incorrect.
Have you already tested `$.getJSON('api/student/'+searchedId)` and seen what it returns ?